# Random Ellipse Generating Program

Tags: c#, wpf

I made this simple program, because I wanna understand basics of WPF but it doesn't work.

In XAML I have only Grid Named `MainGrid` and Button `button1` with action `button1_Click` that looks like this:

```
void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(rnd.Next(0,(int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth-100),rnd.Next(1,(int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight-101),0,0);
        ellipse.Width = 100;
        ellipse.Height = 100;
        ellipse.Name = "ellipseTest";
        if (ellipseShown) {
            MainGrid.Children.Remove((UIElement)MainGrid.FindName("ellipseTest"));
        }
            MainGrid.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
```

But when I click the button previous ellipse doesn't disappear and also sometimes when I click the button it does nothing (do not create new ellipse, do not disappear). Please help, thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't create a new ellipse, then how can you say none disappear? Besides that, do you ever actually set the `ellipseShown` field? There's nothing in the code above that does. You are doing this wrong anyway: you should create a view model data structure that represents the ellipse, then present that model by data template in the XAML. If you only ever want one ellipse at a time, then just have a single model with X and Y. If you want multiple, use `ItemsControl`. In either case, use `Canvas`, not `Grid`, and `Canvas.Left`/`Canvas.Top`, not the `Margin` to locate the object.

Comment: As presented here, your question is far too broad. You haven't included a good [mcve], and your code is too far from what good WPF code would be. An answer based on the above would essentially be to write the program from scratch for you. Here are some links to questions I've answered in the past that are very similar to what you're trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28338925 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/33749132. Perhaps you can use those as a basis for making forward progress on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add/remove objects at runtime to visual tree you need to use RegisterName and UnregisterName to manage the XAML namespace.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        ellipse.Margin = new Thickness(rnd.Next(0, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 100), rnd.Next(1, (int)System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 101), 0, 0);
        ellipse.Width = 100;
        ellipse.Height = 100;
        ellipse.Name = "ellipseTest";
        if (ellipseShown)
        {
            System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse ellipse0 = MainGrid.FindName("ellipseTest") as System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse;
            MainGrid.Children.Remove(ellipse0);
            MainGrid.UnregisterName("ellipseTest");

        }
        MainGrid.RegisterName("ellipseTest", ellipse);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(ellipse);
        ellipseShown = true;
    }
```

See this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx